# Looping through public signupList: Array<Object> using keyvalue in ionic 2

Tags: object, typescript, ionic-framework

How can I loop through public mySentences: Array using keyvalue in ionic 2.
    for example: how can I loop through array in type script? Thanks

```
public mySentences:Array<Object> = [
    {id: 1, text: 'Sentence 1'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Sentence 2'},
    {id: 3, text: 'Sentence 3'},
    {id: 4, text: 'Sentenc4 '},
];
```

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of Javascript, so your array is basically a Javascript array and should find a way on how to iterate over this array on this site.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html